# Trying to install jfrog insights

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-insights

I am trying to install jfrog insights by following the official documentation available on the website using docker-compose method.

**ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yaml' is invalid because:
services.router.ports is invalid: Invalid port ":", should be [[remote_ip:]remote_port[-remote_port]:]port[/protocol]
services.router.ports is invalid: Invalid port ":", should be [[remote_ip:]remote_port[-remote_port]:]port[/protocol]
services.router.ports value [':', ':'] has non-unique elements**

The docker file looks

version: '3'
services:
router:
image: releases-docker.jfrog.io/jfrog/router:${DOCKER_VERSION_ROUTER}
container_name: insight_router
restart: always
environment:
- JF_ROUTER_TOPOLOGY_LOCAL_REQUIREDSERVICETYPES=jfisv,jfisc
- JF_ROUTER_ENTRYPOINTS_EXTERNALPORT=${JF_ROUTER_ENTRYPOINTS_EXTERNALPORT}
ports:
- ${JF_ELASTICSEARCH_TRANSPORTPORT}:${JF_ELASTICSEARCH_TRANSPORTPORT}
- ${JF_ROUTER_ENTRYPOINTS_EXTERNALPORT}:${JF_ROUTER_ENTRYPOINTS_EXTERNALPORT} # for router communication
user: "${INSIGHT_USER}:${INSIGHT_USER}"
volumes:
- /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
- "${ROOT_DATA_DIR}/var:/var/opt/jfrog/router"
scheduler:
image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/jfrog/insight-scheduler:${DOCKER_VERSION_JFSC}
container_name: insight_scheduler
restart: always
volumes:
- /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
- "${ROOT_DATA_DIR}/var:/var/opt/jfrog/insight"
logging:
driver: json-file
options:
max-size: 50m
max-file: '10'
network_mode: service:router
insight_server:
image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/jfrog/insight-server:${DOCKER_VERSION_JFIS}
container_name: insight_server
restart: always
volumes:
- /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
- "${ROOT_DATA_DIR}/var:/var/opt/jfrog/insight"
logging:
driver: json-file
options:
max-size: 50m
max-file: '10'
network_mode: service:router
elasticsearch:
entrypoint: ""
command: /bin/bash -c " (/usr/local/bin/initializeSearchGuard.sh &) && docker-entrypoint.sh 'elasticsearch'"
image: releases-docker.jfrog.io/jfrog/elasticsearch-sg:7.16.3
container_name: insight_elasticsearch
volumes:
- /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
- "${ROOT_DATA_DIR}/var/data/elasticsearch/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data"
- "${ROOT_DATA_DIR}/var/log/elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/logs"
- "${ROOT_DATA_DIR}/var/data/elasticsearch/config/jvm.options.d:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/jvm.options.d"
- "${ROOT_DATA_DIR}/var/data/elasticsearch/sgconfig:/usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/search-guard-7/sgconfig"
- "${ROOT_DATA_DIR}/var/data/elasticsearch/config/unicast_hosts.txt:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/unicast_hosts.txt"
environment:
- transport.host=0.0.0.0
- transport.port=9300
- transport.publish_host=${HOST_IP}
- bootstrap.memory_lock=true
- node.name=${HOST_IP}
- discovery.seed_providers=file
- $ES_MASTER_NODE_SETTINGS
- ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=**REPLACE_ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME**
- ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=**REPLACE_ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD**
- ELASTICSEARCH_CLUSTERSETUP=${JF_ELASTICSEARCH_CLUSTERSETUP}
restart: always
ulimits:
memlock:
soft: -1
hard: -1
nofile:
soft: 65536
hard: 65536
cap_add:
- IPC_LOCK
logging:
driver: json-file
options:
max-size: 50m
max-file: '10'
network_mode: service:router

Comment: Can you confirm if you ran the config.sh script?

Comment: @PrasannaRaghavendra I did not get your point.

Answer (score 0):

Hamza - can you confirm if you are using this latest documentation - https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Installing+Insight

This has a step (step #3) to run installer script `./config.sh` - did you run it?

Comment: root@desrvas133:/opt/containerd/jfrog-insight-1.7.0-compose#  docker-compose -p insight up -d
WARNING: Found multiple config files with supported names: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml
WARNING: Using docker-compose.yml

ERROR: Named volume "yes/var:/var/opt/jfrog/router:rw" is used in service "router" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.

Comment: I run the step 3 now and got the error

Comment: Please delete the entire folder `jfrog-insight-1.7.0-compose` , redo from scratch and follow the steps 1 to 3 - can you share the steps run here. We feel one of the steps is missed out. Also confirm .env file is present in the root folder for docker-compose to pick up.